# Salvar entidade rest usando @oneToMany

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

Tenho as seguintes entidades geradas pelo jHipster usando java com relacionamento oneToMany:

**Produto**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "produto")
public class Produto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Imagem> imagems = new HashSet<>();

//demais campos
//gets e sets
```

**Imagem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imagem")
public class Imagem implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Lob
@Column(name = "bl_imagem")
private byte[] blImagem;

@Column(name = "bl_imagem_content_type")
private String blImagemContentType;

@ManyToOne
private Produto produto;

//gets e sets
```

**Servico rest**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/produtos",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Produto> createProduto(@Valid @RequestBody Produto produto) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to save Produto : {}", produto);
    if (produto.getId() != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert("produto", "idexists", "A new produto cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
    }
    Produto result = produtoService.save(produto);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/produtos/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("produto", result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

**Meu jSon no frontend feito em angularJs**

[image: Post]

**Pergunta:**

O backend está salvando o produto na tabela produto, mas não salva nada na tabela imagem, como eu poderia fazer esse relacionamento oneToMany, sendo que um produto pode possuir várias imagens?

Comment: Você tem que definir o produto no objeto imagem e salvar o objeto imagem.

Comment: Mas se eu já tenho as imagens dentro do produto, eu queria que ao salvar o produto as imagens fossem automaticamente salvas na tabela, por que se não terei que criar dois métodos post.

Comment: Parece que o problema é no  @RequestBody, por que ao entrar no método da classe rest a lista está vazia.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, é que no json o nome da pripriedade é: imagem e no backend está: imagems. Eu alterei e deu certo, agora as imagens são salvas automaticamente.

Porém estou com outro problema, ele não salva o campo produto_id na tabela imagem para cada imagem. Queria alguma forma disso ser feito automaticamente tbm pelo hibernate

Comment: Oxi, se ele não salva o produto_id na tabela imagem, como que o hibernate fez a relação?

Comment: Se a anotação **@JoinColumn(name = "produto_id")** ele adiciona sem preencher o campo produto_id na tabela imagem, porém no select ele não traz nenhuma imagem, apenas insere no post. @Matheus_Silva

Comment: Acho que tu tem que definir o produto no objeto imagem, mesmo que não salve a imagem, apenas defina na imagem e salve o produto e deixar que o hibernate salve os dois. Porque pelo jeito, deve estar salvando os dois objetos sem fazer a relação entre eles. Relacionamentos bidirecionais são assim, tem que informar aos dois a quem estão ligados. Exige mais cuidado.

Answer (score 1):

Para o primeiro problema, apenas alterei o nome da propriedade no json de imagem para imagems para ficar igual ao backend.

No caso de salvar o id do produto para cada registro na tabela imagem, coloquei:

`@JoinColumn(name = "produto_id")`

Que faça o update no id automaticamente.